# Why is a spot on my ceiling bleeding through even after using a priming sealer?

Tags: paint, primer

I had water spots and used Kilz and now the Kilz is bleeding through my ceiling paint.

Comment: did you use a stain blocking primer after the kilz?

Comment: How long has the ceiling been drying?  Ceiling paint will be slower to dry over kilz than elsewhere. That will make the area appear darker until fully dry.

Comment: Has the issue that caused the water spots been fixed?

Comment: I suspect that you're not seeing "bleeding", but a variation in sheen from spot-priming. You really should cover an entire wall or ceiling area when priming so that the preparation is uniform.

Comment: I find kilz to be only moderately effective and only on minor staining, I use Zinsser shellac based primer if i want to cover with confidence.

Comment: @isherwood  Correctamundo but they got some that's for medium stains and some for tough stains so that might have been the problem.

Comment: I use both but think zinsser to be a superior product .+